# apple service can not create 3 key service with apns

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apn

I am new in apple developer. I have problem when create apns key for my app ( there 2 key service before).

Here is my capture screen
[image]

After a lot of searchs, I still dont know why? I read apple doc that say only using apn key to make ios app can get remote notification. Other key is not working. Please help me know it. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check your past keys, as [mentioned here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180901130531/https://hackry.io/) (click on "Read the Guides", then "Push Notifications"):

> The Key Id and Certificate File is obtained by [creating a new key](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey/create).
> Enter a name for the key and select the APNs service.
> This key is used for all your apps, so if “You have already reached the maximum allowed number of Keys for this service” look back at your [list of your keys](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/authkey/) for an APNs service key.
> When the key is generated, make sure to download and back up the certificate file as it will not be accessible in the future.

Maybe you can check in your list of keys for the APNs service keys, and or try to delete/recreate said keys.

Comment: thanks you. I have a question: if "keys" is used for all app, I create 2 keys but never used it for other things. I dont know why I have to create key while it does not help me in fcm docs introduce.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: @kemdo Do you mean you cannot create anew key (in order to upload it to Firebase)? (as in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_authentication_key)

Comment: @kemdo How did you overcome from this problem? Is it like, I have to use the same key for different projects?

Comment: @Tulon Dont use Firebase cloud msg use one signal instead

Comment: Why is that? Can you please explain your point of view? I already implemented that.